# Get Text in Dynamic Events with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom

I'm trying to get the text from tag `<a>` in element `<li>`  but it doesn't work.

```js
for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  $("#ftrBtn-menu_Facility").append("<li id='ftrBtn-menu_Facility_" + (i) + "'><a href='#'>" + result[i].facility + "</a></li>");
  $("#ftrBtn-menu_Facility_" + (i)).click(function(){
    var text = $("#ftrBtn-menu_Facility_" + (i)).find("a:first").text();
    alert(text);
  });
}
```

Comment: Short answer: Just use `var text = $(this).find("a:first").text()` indide your click

Comment: This is a prime example of why you shouldn't use auto-generated `id` attributes. You could use a closure, or just `var text = $(this).find("a:first").text();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you dont just use class instead of using id ?
Here's my proposed solution

```js
var result = [{
  id: 1,
  facility: 'test1'
}, {
  id: 2,
  facility: 'test2'
}, {
  id: 3,
  facility: 'test3'
}]
for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  $("#ftrBtn-menu_Facility").append("<li class='dtrBtn' id='ftrBtn-menu_Facility_" + (i) + "'><a href='#'>" + result[i].facility + "</a></li>");

}
$(".dtrBtn").click(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  alert(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ftrBtn-menu_Facility"></div>
```